# Calculator on JavaScript(simple)

Tags: javascript

In the text field, you need to specify the values ​​and count them by the button. I do not understand why not think so? You need to implement it in principle through a switch but I can not understand why operations are not counted: +, -, *, /

```
<p>
  <label for="text1">FirstNum</label> 
  <input type="text" id="text1"><br>
  <label for="operation">Operation</label> 
  <input type="text" id="operation"><br>
  <label for="text2">SecondNum</label> 
  <input type="text" id="text2"><br>
  <label for="text3">Result</label> 
  <input type="text" id="text3"><br><br>
  <input type="button" value="ClickResult" onclick="Calc()">
</p>

<script>

  function Calc(operation) {
    //var op;
    switch(operation) {
      case '+':
        text3.value = text1.value + text2.value;
        break;
      case '-':
        text3.value = text1.value - text2.value;
        break;
      case '/':
        text3.value = text1.value / text2.value;
        break;
      case '*':
        text3.value = text1.value * text2.value;
        break;
    }      
 }

</script>
```

Comment: 1. I think you'll need to clarify your question as I'm finding it unclear. 2. Show example input to `Calc`. 3. `value` fields are typically strings. You need to parse them as numbers before you can do math on them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the values of textbox like so:

```
   var text1 = document.getElementById('text1').value;
```

But the value you get is in string format, so you need to convert it into int or float so you have to typecast it into int or float like so:

```
   text1 = parseFloat(text1);
```

and then give out the value in the result box like so:

```
document.getElementById('text3').value = result of the calculation
```

or another way is:

```
var result = document.getElementById('text3');
result.value = result of computation
```

```html
<p>
  <label for="text1">FirstNum</label> 
  <input type="text" id="text1"><br>
  <label for="operation">Operation</label> 
  <input type="text" id="operation"><br>
  <label for="text2">SecondNum</label> 
  <input type="text" id="text2"><br>
  <label for="text3">Result</label> 
  <input type="text" id="text3"><br><br>
  <input type="button" value="ClickResult" onclick="Calc()">
</p>
       
<script>

  function Calc() {
    var text1 = document.getElementById('text1').value;
    var text2 = document.getElementById('text2').value;
    var operation = document.getElementById('operation').value;
    var text3 = document.getElementById('text3');
    text1 = parseFloat(text1);
    text2 = parseFloat(text2);
    //var op;
    switch(operation) {
      case '+':
        text3.value = text1 + text2;
        break;
      case '-':
        text3.value = text1 - text2;
        break;
      case '/':
        text3.value = text1 / text2;
        break;
      case '*':
        text3.value = text1 * text2;
        break;
    }

  }
  
</script>
```

Comment: You don't have to `parseFloat()` when you could just coerce the string to be a number by just prepending the unary operator `+` so `text1 = parseFloat(text1)` could just be `text1 = +text1`. In general I would recommend avoiding `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` since all numbers in JavaScript are floats following the [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) standard. There are use cases for `parseInt()` and `parseFloat()`, but this should not be one of them.

Comment: @spex thanks for info, may be you right, i redone parseFloat to +text1 and +text2